# How to remove single gem from all gemsets

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, gemset

I need to remove capybara-webkit gem from all gemsets, because I upgraded libqt and I need to rebuild native-extensions. Is there a simple method to remove a gem from all RVM gemsets to avoid running

```
gem uninstall capybara-webkit
```

for all of them manually?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall capybara-webkit
```